# How to get last 12 moths data from today when I am using timestamp field?

Tags: timestamp, intervals, psql

This is my code:

```
AND M_Transaction.movementdate >= date_trunc('month', now()) - interval '12 month' and
      M_Transaction.movementdate < date_trunc('month', now())
```

I got this error:`[Err] ORA-30089: missing or invalid <datetime field>`

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```
DateTime myDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-12);
```

After, you can convert this date in timestamp if you want.